# Why `void 0` could be “faster” than `undefined`?

Tags: javascript, performance

Just lurking over weird and fancy stuff at [140byte docs](https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques) and found [this](https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques#use-_-instead-of-undefined):

> `void 0` is faster than `undefined` but longer than the alternatives.

I lazy checked right in the Chrome console like this:

```
console.time('void');
for (let a = 0; a < 1e6; a++) {() => void 0};
console.timeEnd('void');
```

vs.

```
console.time('undefined');
for (let a = 0; a < 1e6; a++) {() => undefined};
console.timeEnd('undefined');
```

And found no difference. Maybe my lazy check is too lazy, or just the statement about the slowness isn’t relevant anymore.

I’m just wondering about the JS engines internals and how it could be possible? How can we talk about the speed of primitives and operators? Is it correct and relevant? It sounds a little bit odd to me.

Comment: You're defining a function 1000000 times and not doing anything with it. What's the point of this question?

Comment: That document actually links to a proper test: https://jsperf.com/undefineds … Which shows barely any difference worth mentioning.

Comment: Well, how to check this right? The point of this question is how we talk about the speed of primitives.

Comment: Oh, OK guys, too much blame, maybe I should just to remove my question?

Comment: > That document actually links to a proper test. Well, that test even more non-sense than mine. Its signature just a `undefined`, no functions, no execution, nothing.

Comment: It tests how long Javascript takes to evaluate the expression `undefined`. Which is exactly what you want to measure (…or is it?). You don't want to add any other overhead because that hides how much time the thing you're trying to test takes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I’m just wondering about the JS engines internals and how it could be possible? How can we talk about the speed of primitives and operators? Is it correct and relevant? It sounds a little bit odd to me.

Yes, it's possible. `undefined` is a global variable, not a keyword. That means it can be shadowed. So in order to find its value, the JavaScript engine is required to walk through the scope chain and check for an `"undefined"` binding at each and every scope level. So for instance:

```
function outer() {
    function middle() {
        function inner() {
            console.log(undefined);
        }
        inner();
    }
    middle();
}
outer();
```

That reference inside `inner` requires that the JavaScript engine check the `inner` function's execution context's binding object, then the `middle`'s, then `outer`'s, before finally finding it at the global level. (Of course, JavaScript engines can optimize that if it seems reasonable to do so.)

In contrast, `void` is a keyword for the `void` operator and `0` is a literal, so `void 0` requires no scope chain traversal. Since the `void` operator is defined as *always* returning `undefined`, there's a mechanism for it to perform better than the `undefined` global.

**Not that it's likely to matter.** You're more likely doing *other* things that will impact your performance.

FWIW, a naive benchmark:

```js
var x = undefined;

var now = performance && performance.now ? performance.now.bind(performance) : Date.now.bind(Date);

function outermost() {
  var a = Math.random();
  function outer() {
    var b = Math.random();
    function inner() {
      var c = Math.random();
      function test1() {
        if (Math.random() > 1) { // Never true
          x = 42;
        }
        return x == undefined;
      }

      function test2() {
        if (Math.random() > 1) { // Never true
          x = 42;
        }
        return x == void 0;
      }

      function test(f, n) {
        var start = now();
        while (n-- > 0) {
          f();
        }
        return now() - start;
      }

      console.log("Testing...");
      setTimeout(function() {
        test(test1, 100000000); // warmup
        test(test2, 100000000); // warmup
        console.log("undefined", test(test1, 1000000000), "ms");
        console.log("void 0   ", test(test2, 1000000000), "ms");
      }, 40);

      if (a + b + c > Infinity) {
        console.log("Impossible, just making sure to use a, b, and c");
      }
    }
    inner();
  }
  outer();
}
outermost();
```

```html
WARNING: THIS MAY LOCK UP YOUR BROWSER WINDOW.
For me, it runs fine on recent Chrome, taking about 20 seconds; YMMV.
```

Comment: Yep, I know that this is not a place to find any useful perfomance tweaks. It were a kind of "esoteric" feature to me. Anyway your answer is what I looked for, thanks!